# Using em-dash instead of parentheses and commas

Tags: punctuation, commas, parentheses, dashes

Let's say I have the following sentence:
"I didn't like the cake (the cookies were better), but I absolutely hated the egg rolls."

Would it be grammatically correct (and colloquially okay, to someone who would be reading it) to change it to this:

"I didn't like the cake—the cookies were better—but I absolutely hated the egg rolls."

because I think it's okay to use em dashes instead of parentheses (according to other questions I've read), but I'm taking out the comma before "but" too. Is that okay?

Comment: Informally, it's perfect and looks much cleaner. You're good to go.

Comment: grammar is not punctuation.